# Docker - flag provided but not defined: -–publish

Tags: macos, docker

I'm a new comer to docker and trying to install redmine using a docker image [from these instructions](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine#quick-start).

The command for the postgresql image works fine, but the command to run the redmine image does not:

```
bash-3.2$ docker run --name=redmine -d \
>   --publish=10083:80 -–publish=10445:443 \
>   --env='REDMINE_PORT=10445' --env='REDMINE_HTTPS=true' \
>   --link=postgresql-redmine:postgresql \
>   --volume=/Users/Josuah/docker/redmine:/home/redmine \
> sameersbn/redmine:3.1.1
flag provided but not defined: -–publish
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I'm using MAC OSX 10.9.5, and installed docker using [the docker tool box](https://www.docker.com/toolbox). I'm running it in a terminal, following [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#from-your-shell).

I don't know what additional information may be useful, so please feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the other syntax option in [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports), which is `-p`

```
-p 10083:80

-p []
```

> Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host
>   format:

```
ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort
```

Also make sure you have connected to your docker VM first, meaning the bash is not the one from a Mac shell session, but one from the VM itself: check `docker info` and `docker version` output.

Finally, make sure you don't type the '`>`' at the beginning of that multi-line command:

```
bash-3.2$ docker run --name=redmine -d \
   --publish=10083:80 -–publish=10445:443 \
   --env='REDMINE_PORT=10445' --env='REDMINE_HTTPS=true' \
   --link=postgresql-redmine:postgresql \
   --volume=/Users/Josuah/docker/redmine:/home/redmine \
 sameersbn/redmine:3.1.1
```

Comment: `--publish` works on my linux box with no issues aswell, its just an equivalent to `-p`, but just a shorter flag, refer `man getopts`

Comment: @askb I agree, which is why I referenced it as "the other syntax", just to check if that helps here.

Comment: ah good point, maybe its an implementation issue on the platform.

Comment: Thank you; I actually did not type '>' at the beginning of the lines, this was just a copy/paste of the output of the terminal. Seems I did a few mistakes while trying to make HTTPS work. I actually changed the paths, trying to adapt to my access rights. I just drop HTTPS and used the simple commands provided without modifying, and it works. I'll try HTTPS again later on.

Comment: @JosuahAron no problem. I was just trying to cover all the possible causes for error there.